# How do I move vertices in relation to pivot?

Tags: transforms, normals, transform-orientation

I would like to move multiples selections towards or outwards 3d cursor, or any other pivot, within orientation to View.
For example :  For example faces on top of the grass lump in blend file. All of their normals are pointing up, but I want to move them equally far in outwards direction from Cursor3D.
Can do I do this using G shortcut ?

https://blend-exchange.com/b/mjOp1XpQ/

Comment: It sounds as if Scaling with the pivot point set to the 3D cursor might be what you want, but please add an image demonstrating exactly what you need. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=mjOp1XpQ" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/mjOp1XpQ/)

For example faces on top of the grass lump. All of their normals are pointing up, but I want to move them equally far in outwards direction from Cursor3D

Comment: Please edit your question and insert that image into it  with an accompanying explanation as I suggested and is explained in the link rather than just putting the link into a comment! That way your question will be resubmited and everyone will see it.

Comment: edited, thank You